# Proof help: every element of A/J is its own negative iff $x+x\in J$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation

Could someone please help me understand this proof? In my course, I was struggling with this proof and the instructor put this woman's up for everyone to see but I just don't follow it. It seems like she repeats her steps for no reason?

> Let A be a ring and J an ideal of A. Prove that every element of A/J is its own negative iff $x+x\in J$ for every $x\in A$.

Pf: J has a unity element and the unity element of A/J is a coset such that for any $x\in A$ $(j+a)(j+x)=J+x$ and $(j+x)(j+a)=J+x$. Now $(j^2+aj+bj+ar)=j+x$ and $(j^2+aj+bj+ar)=j+x$ so $(j+ax)=j+x$ and $(j+ax)=j+x$. Then $ax-x\in J$ and $ax-x\in J$ for any $x\in A$.

Answer (score 4):

The statement follows from the equivalence
$$x+J=-x+J\Leftrightarrow x+x+J=J \Leftrightarrow x+x\in J$$

Comment: I apologize I do not see how the proof follows from this? (Or how this follows from the proof?)

Comment: The elements of $A/J$ are the cosets $c+J$.  The negative of the coset $c+J$ is the coset $-c+J$.